# Disable Keyguard and START STICKY not working with Android for BlackBerry

Tags: android, service, blackberry, sticky, keyguard

Im trying to port an android app to BB and Im having some issues with a few things.  First off, when this app starts it creates a service that listens for certain events whether the application is in foreground or background.  If the service is killed, I want it to automatically restart.  here is my code for this in the service itself:

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // Other code here...

```
 // this will restart service if killed.  
return START_STICKY
```

}

This works as expected in Android, but will not restart the service on BB.  Has anyone experienced this?

Second off, I am trying relaunch an activity if the device is turned off.  Therefore, I have created a wake lock to turn the screen on, and then  I disable the keyguard and finally launch the activity.  Unfortunately, I cannot disable the keyguard.  My code to disable keyguard is below, has anyone experienced this?

KeyguardManager Keylockmgr = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
Keylockmgr.newKeyguardLock("My Tag").disableKeyguard();

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works as expected in Android, but will not restart the service on BB. Has anyone experienced this?

Quoting the BlackBerry documentation:

> Background service: Apps can run services only while the user runs them, either in full screen or in thumbnail mode.

Now, I'm a bit hazy on "thumbnail mode", but my interpretation of this is that `START_STICKY` will be ignored.

> Unfortunately, I cannot disable the keyguard

According to [the BlackBerry documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupported_api_jellybean_app_permission.html), `DISABLE_KEYGUARD` is not supported.